# "In undertaking a review" vs. "by undertaking a review"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> - **In** undertaking a literature review,  it became clear that not always is there coherence between the principles...
> - **By** undertaking a literature review, it became clear that not always is there coherence between the principles...

Is there any difference between using *by* and *in* here? The literature review has already been carried out, if that matters.

Comment: *In* is incorrect in this sentence. The correct preposition would be *by*: "By undertaking a literature review ..."

Comment: The context following the example suggests a different tense is required than what was given.  Among the other concerns, I think it may be a better candidate for writers, per the guidance outlined within by @Kris.

Comment: @JustinC I don't think Writers would want this at all. It's about the preposition to use in this situation, which is definitely on topic here, within reason

Answer (score 6):

I think `Through a review of the literature, it became clear that` or something similar is better than either.  Both `in` and `by` seem to imply connection or causality between the undertaking of the review and the meaning of the review undertaken.  (Of the two, I believe that `In ...` is better.  )

That which is learned from the review, unless I'm mistaken, is not dependent on the undertaking of the review.

Comment: This is a good answer. Neither of OP's versions can easily be salvaged so long as that word *undertaking* stays there. Your suggested rewording involves relatively minimal changes, *and* uses perfectly natural phrasing.

Comment: What FumbleFingers says. Or even more simply, "A review of the literature revealed that ... "

Comment: All of these dodge the issue that ***it*** didn't do any such thing as *becoming clear*. In fact, _clear_ is a perceptual predicate, which presupposes a human perceiver, who is not identified here, and who is not owning up to the responsibility for describing the perception. That unidentified perceiver (provisionally identified with the equally unidentified reviewer of the literature already presupposed) needs to be mentioned. I.e, _it became clear **to me** that ..._  Otherwise you're lying.

Comment: Unlike on writersSE, the purpose of a question here is **not** proof-reading or improving the literarily. It is better not to suggest alternatives when not specifically asked for. It seems the OP likes to know the difference in using the prepositions *in* and *by* in a sentence like the one given.

Answer (score 1):

when "in undertaking a review"  is used in a conversation to someone , it would imply that the addressee is being asked to embark on a systematic search of the available and accessible literature to compile a document supporting his/her claim or theory. This may vary from subject to subject.

In science this would mean that the practical aspect is to be compiled into a scientific document after taking stock of all published literature on the topic until the current date. The researcher would also have to incorporate his/her work as a new recent development in this area.

In arts however the researcher should delve into the library bookshelves (online and hard) accumulating all the literature there is on the subject. He/she then has the freedom to compile a document on the topic to either publish or to incorporate as a thesis chapter. science doesnt allow you to put reviews as your thesis chapters..(correct me if iam wrong)

BY undertaking a review is a form of reported speech when the author is justifying his findings based on the exhaustive review he/she has prepared ....